# Plotting series of pdfs and cdfs with different parameters

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I am hoping to reproduce something similar to [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#/media/File:Rayleigh_distributionPDF.svg) in R. My goal is to plot a series of pdf and/or cdfs on the same graph of the Rayleigh and other distributions with different parameters. Ideally I would like to coerce an identical sequence of x values along with a sequence of parameter values into a data frame which would then be plotted using ggplot.

So far I've tried a few permuatations of:

"Scale <- c(0.5,1,2,3,4); x <- seq(-1, 12, by = 0.1), y <- VGAM::drayleigh(x, scale = Scale[i])".

What would be the best way to go about this? I've made a few attempts using for loops and rep(seq(...)) but no success. Thank you.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this question is off-topic here because of its primary emphasis on programming. I'll try to give skeletal code using the base of R, and leave `ggplot` to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rayleigh distribution with scale parameter $\sigma,$ has
density function $f(x) = \frac{x}{\sigma^2}\exp\left[-.5(\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2})\right],$ for $x,\sigma > 0.$ If plotting a density function in the base of R, then
use `dnorm`, `dgamma`, etc., as appropriate. [The procedure `curve` requires an
argument in `x`.]

```
m = 5;  sg = c(.5,1,2,3,4)
frb=c("blue", "darkgreen", "red", "cyan4", "purple")
hdr="Densities of Rayleigh Distributions: Scale = 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4"
plot(c(0,11),c(0,1.2), col="white", ylab="Density", xlab="x", main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="grey");  abline(v=0, col="grey")
for(i in 1:m) {
 curve((x/sg[i]^2)*exp(-.5*(x^2/sg[i]^2)), add=T, col=frb[i])
 }
```

[image]